# How can I calculate arbitrary values from a spline created with scipy.interpolate.Rbf?

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I have several data points in 3 dimensional space `(x, y, z)` and have interpolated them using `scipy.interpolate.Rbf`. This gives me a spline nicely representing the surface of my 3D object. I would now like to determine several `x` and `y` pairs that have the same, arbitrary `z` value. I would like to do that in order to compute the cross section of my 3D object at any given value of `z`. Does someone know how to do that? Maybe there is also a better way to do that instead of using `scipy.interpolate.Rbf`.

Up to now I have evaluated the cross sections by making a contour plot using `matplotlib.pyplot` and extracting the displayed segments. [3D points and interpolated spline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJj8Q.png)
[segments extracted using a contour plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzJws.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I have calculated the area by triangulating the x-y data and cutting the triangles with the z-plane I wanted to calculate the cross-sectional area of (`z=z0`). Specifically, I have searched for those triangles whose z-values are both above and below z0. Then I have calculated the x and y values of the sides of these triangles where the sides are equal to `z0`. Then I use `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` to sort the intersected points. Using the shoelace formula I can then determine the area.

I have attached the example code here:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generation of random test data
n = 500
x = np.random.random(n) 
y = np.random.random(n)
z = np.exp(-2*(x-.5)**2-4*(y-.5)**2)

z0 = .75

# Triangulation of the test data
triang= spatial.Delaunay(np.array([x, y]).T)


# Determine all triangles where not all points are above or below z0, i.e. the triangles that intersect z0
tri_inter=np.zeros_like(triang.simplices, dtype=np.int) # The triangles which intersect the plane at z0, filled below

i = 0
for tri in triang.simplices:    
    if ~np.all(z[tri] > z0) and ~np.all(z[tri] < z0):
        tri_inter[i,:] = tri
        i += 1
tri_inter = tri_inter[~np.all(tri_inter==0, axis=1)] # Remove all rows with only 0 

# The number of interpolated values for x and y has twice the length of the triangles
# Because each triangle intersects the plane at z0 twice
x_inter = np.zeros(tri_inter.shape[0]*2)
y_inter = np.zeros(tri_inter.shape[0]*2)

for j, tri in enumerate(tri_inter):

    # Determine which of the three points are above and which are below z0
    points_above = []
    points_below = []

    for i in tri:    
        if z[i] > z0:
            points_above.append(i)
        else:
            points_below.append(i)     

    # Calculate the intersections and put the values into x_inter and y_inter
    t = (z0-z[points_below[0]])/(z[points_above[0]]-z[points_below[0]])
    x_new = t * (x[points_above[0]]-x[points_below[0]]) + x[points_below[0]]
    y_new = t * (y[points_above[0]]-y[points_below[0]]) + y[points_below[0]]

    x_inter[j*2] = x_new
    y_inter[j*2] = y_new

    if len(points_above) > len(points_below): 
        t = (z0-z[points_below[0]])/(z[points_above[1]]-z[points_below[0]])
        x_new = t * (x[points_above[1]]-x[points_below[0]]) + x[points_below[0]]
        y_new = t * (y[points_above[1]]-y[points_below[0]]) + y[points_below[0]]

    else:
        t = (z0-z[points_below[1]])/(z[points_above[0]]-z[points_below[1]])
        x_new = t * (x[points_above[0]]-x[points_below[1]]) + x[points_below[1]]
        y_new = t * (y[points_above[0]]-y[points_below[1]]) + y[points_below[1]]

    x_inter[j*2+1] = x_new
    y_inter[j*2+1] = y_new

# sort points to calculate area
hull = spatial.ConvexHull(np.array([x_inter, y_inter]).T)

x_hull, y_hull = x_inter[hull.vertices], y_inter[hull.vertices]

# Calculation of are using the shoelace formula
area = 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x_hull,np.roll(y_hull,1))-np.dot(y_hull,np.roll(x_hull,1)))

print('Area:', area)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_inter, y_inter, 'ro')
plt.plot(x_hull, y_hull, 'b--')
plt.triplot(x, y, triangles=tri_inter, color='k')
plt.show()
```